# Detect change of state in image in regard to reference image

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

Firstly, i would like to highlight I am a beginner in this field.
I have a board-like object in a reference(train) image with a empty backgammon-like table so there are no pieces on it. My task is to find the pieces/tokens(exactly like the backgammon ones) on the table in a second picture where the image might be slightly rotated , scaled or with some different lighting. I use SIFT algorithm from cv2 and most of the keypoints match in both pictures (here i have to add this table is not 100% a backgammon table so there are not multiple identical regions that might be wrongfully matched). How should I progress ahead in order to detect these pieces(tokens) on the table ?

I am thinking about a geometric approach where i basically try to undo the test picture changes and find a map between the second image pixels and the first image pixels and once i have this done i can simply subtract the images and get the tokens. Is this the right approach to this problem or are there any better algorithms or techniques for such task?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SIFT (Scale Invariant Feature Transform) algorithm for object recognition in images. SIFT is a feature detection algorithm in computer vision that detects and describes local features in images1. You can use OpenCV library to implement SIFT algorithm2.

To detect and draw keypoints in the input image using SIFT algorithm, you could follow the steps given below3:

1. Import the required libraries OpenCV and NumPy.
2. Read the input image using cv2.imread() method.
3. Specify the full path of the image.
4. Convert the input image into grayscale using cv2.cvtColor() method.
5. Create a SIFT detector object using cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
   method.
6. Detect keypoints in the grayscale image using sift.detect() method.
7. Draw keypoints on the original image using cv2.drawKeypoints()
   method.

Once you have detected keypoints in both images, you can match them using a feature matching algorithm such as FLANN (Fast Library for Approximate Nearest Neighbors) or brute-force matcher4. Once you have matched keypoints between two images, you can estimate a homography matrix that maps one image onto another5. This homography matrix can be used to transform one image into another so that they are aligned with each other5.

Once you have aligned two images, you can subtract one from another to get the tokens/pieces on the table5. However, this approach might not work well if there are significant differences between two images such as occlusion or changes in lighting conditions5. In such cases, you might need to use more advanced techniques such as deep learning-based object detection algorithms5.